# retrieving a value from nested dictionary API

Tags: python, django

Im trying to ovveride a POST request from API View and i requested a form like that:

```
{
"chp_reference":"522", "income_period":"Weekly", "property_market_rent":"400",
"number_of_family_group":"3", "rent_effective_date":"2020-12-4",
"state":"NSW",
"family_group": [
    {
        "name":"FG_1"
    },
    {
        "name": "FG_2"
    }
],
"family_member":[
    {
        "name":"FG_1"
    }
]
}
```

`FamilyGroup` is a child model to `Transaction` , `FamilyMember` is also a child for `Transaction` and `FamilyGroup`

im trying to make a POST request that Include `FamilyGroup` and `Familymember` inside `Transaction`
like that:

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def post_api(request):
    transaction_data = request.data
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=transaction_data)
    family_groups = transaction_data["family_group"]
    family_members = transaction_data["family_group"]
    fg_ids = []
    

    new_transaction = Transaction.objects.create(chp_reference=transaction_data['chp_reference'],
                        income_period=transaction_data['income_period'],
                        property_market_rent=transaction_data['property_market_rent'],
                        number_of_family_group=transaction_data['number_of_family_group'],
                        rent_effective_date=transaction_data['rent_effective_date'],
                        state=transaction_data['state'])
    new_transaction.save()
    for fg in family_groups:
        c = FamilyGroup(name=fg["name"], transaction=new_transaction )

    c.save()
    for fm in family_members:
        b = FamilyMember( transaction=new_transaction, family_group=c, name=fm["name"] )
    b.save()
    return Response('Added')
```

but when doing so , im only getting `FG_2` , basically it returns me the last `name` of `FamilyGroup` and `FamilyMember`... I would like to return the whole list of names.. would appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're creating multiple `FamilyGroup` and `FamilyMember` instances, but only *saving* the last because your `save()` call falls outside your for loop:

```
    for fg in family_groups:
        c = FamilyGroup(name=fg["name"], transaction=new_transaction )

    c.save()
```

Move the `save()` calls into the `for` loop if you want to save each of them.

```
    for fg in family_groups:
        c = FamilyGroup(name=fg["name"], transaction=new_transaction)
        c.save()
```

Comment: thank you for your response, now im getting an error 'dict' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Comment: Oh, wait, never mind. I overlooked your actual error because `QueryDict`'s multivalue behavior is such a common thing to miss.

Comment: Thank you, this work excellent, had to pay more attention ;)